# Stop a video playing upon closing a form

Tags: c#, video

I have created a form that will play a video upon loading. However I cannot figure out how to get the video to stop playing when the user exits the form. I have tried some other solutions that people have used but they don't seem to work.

When I say the video doesn't stop playing I mean that the audio from the video can still be heard even after the form containing the video has been closed.

Any suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RRAS
{
    public partial class frmVideoTutorial : Form
    {
        formRRAS _main;
        public frmVideoTutorial(formRRAS main)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _main = main;

        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void frmVideoTutorial_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"F:\Group Project\RRAS\RRAS\RRAS\Tutorial.mp4";
        }

        private void frm_close(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
            {
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.close();
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe `axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Stop();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to the form properties and go to the events. Click on FormClosed event. From there just add the code to make the player stop, upon form exit.

I was having a similar issue, and that's what I done to fix it. I had asked the same question, except it was for bringing another form up.

This should do the trick. Be sure to do it on each form that has a video. That you want stopped upon exiting.

Use the .Stop();

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your welcome.. Let me know if it works. That is based on the main form closing. You can do the same if you do a borderless form. After adding mouse click events, you can make custom buttons for exit and minimize and maximize. You would put the same thing as form close event except it will be in the btnClose event.

Comment: i know it can be tricky at times. But everything is working now, correct?